# Google Chrome on Mac and localhost issues

Tags: google-chrome, browser

Just wondering, has anyone installed Google Chrome on Mac OSX and can no longer connect to localhost websites?

I've just installed Google Chrome, only change I've made and all my browsers can no longer find any of my sites on my Mac.

Comment: Is httpd running? ps aux | grep httpd

Comment: Yes httpd is running

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste anyone's time, I forgot I had to remove the logs folder for a particular vhost because of SVN issues.  'apachectl configtest' or 'apachectl restart' do not supply any errors about a logs folder missing - instead apache stops working all together (great !).